# Ggplot2 graphic package tools

Tags: ggplot2, time-series

I'm using the ggplot package tools, with the autoplot (fit) function I got the graph that shows the distribution of the model's unit roots, but I'm not clear how to interpret this graph. I thank anyone who can help me

[image]

Comment: The graph appears to from the forecast package, not the ggplot2 package. It is explained here: https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arma-roots/

Comment: I appreciate your help